# Reference request on Plancherel measure for partitions whose parts differing by more than $1$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

Given an (unrestricted) integer partition $\lambda$ of $n$, let $f_{\lambda}$ denote the number of standard Young tableaux (SYT) of shape the Young diagram $Y(\lambda)$ of $\lambda$. Then,
$$\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}f_{\lambda}^2=n! \tag1$$
where the sum runs through all partitions of $n$.

Given a restricted (or distinct parts) integer partition $\lambda$ of $n$, let $g_{\lambda}$ denote the number of standard Young tableaux of shape the **shifted** Young diagram $S(\lambda)$ of $\lambda$. Note that distinct parts also means parts that differ by $1$ or more. Then,
$$\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}2^{n-\ell(\lambda)}g_{\lambda}^2=n! \tag2$$
where the sum runs through all partitions into distinct parts of $n$.

These two results allow for probability (Plancherel) measures in their respective environments.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a result analogous to (1) and (2) for integer partitions whose parts differ by $2$ or more?

Comment: A nice combinatorial approach to (1) and (2) is via the dual graded graphs of Fomin (building on Stanley's differential posets). But I don't think this works to give something for partitions whose parts differ by $r$ for $r \geq 2$.